# WCF DataContract hiding Base class

Tags: wcf, dto

How can i avoid exposing my base class and it's member when i expose my Employee DTO, 
(When i do add service reference  there should be no mention of Organization class / it's members).

```
   [Serializable]
    public abstract class Organization
    {
        public string Id{ get; set; }
        public string SSN{ get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract][Serializable]
    public class Employee :Organization
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you need to separate the `Employee` contract out into an interface and expose it through your service.

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class Organization
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public interface IEmployee
{
    [DataMember]
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    string LastName { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Employee : Organization, IEmployee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Define your service as returning an `IEmployee`, and simply return a concrete `Employee` instance.

Comment: repeating the class is the only way ?

Comment: You're not repeating the class, you're using the interface to define *exactly* what's offered by the service. Yes, it looks similar, but it's an entirely different concept.

Comment: @AdamMaras - Why bother defining `IEmployee` if you aren't going to define a solid implementation of it?

Comment: Because I forgot to include that `Employee` implements it in my code sample. Thanks for that catch, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the [Serializable] attribute from both classes and you should be fine. If you use [DataContract] attribue then only properties/fileds with [DataMember] attribute will be available when the proxy is created.

Comment: but i need my class to be serializable as i persist it in view state